# Using DATE_FORMAT to group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing an SQL query in Mysql where the result should be grouped by both an ID and the date. The date is determined dynamically, and can either be a simple datetime field, or a combination of the year and month or week of the year. See the query below for the week of the year case;

```
SELECT t.transactionId, t.transactionDate, t.transactionProcessDate, 
t.status, t.type, t.versionId, t.note, WEEKOFYEAR(t.transactionDate) as CW, 
YEAR(t.transactionDate) as yr, (DATE_FORMAT(t.transactionDate, '%Y-%u')) as tDate
FROM transaction t 
WHERE (t.status = 'A' or t.status = 'N') 
GROUP BY t.transactionId , tDate
```

The problem I have is attempting to group by the tDate,

```
GROUP BY t.transactionId , tDate
```

which returns duplicates with same dates.

When I change the query to group by the CW and yr fields,

```
GROUP BY t.transactionId , CW, yr
```

I get the expected result, without duplicates.

**Question:** Is there a problem with grouping by fields generated by the `DATE_FORMAT`which may result in the returned query not being able to recorgnize duplicates?
I would like to completely exclude the two fields CW and yr from the query since they are used only for grouping.

Comment: have you tried `GROUP BY t.transactionId , t.transactionDate` instead?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Þaw That will not work because the transaction dates may be different.

Comment: @MarkBannister I am not currently on my PC, but it should be at least 5.1.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATED** First of all, it's hard to tell not seeing your real data, but `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.transactionDate, '%Y-%u')` works just fine

```
SELECT transactionId, 
       DATE_FORMAT(transactionDate, '%Y-%u') tDate
       ...
  FROM transaction
 WHERE status IN('A', 'N') 
 GROUP BY transactionId, tDate
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c72f/2)**

**On a side note:** even though MySql allows to specify a field (in your case t.status, t.type etc.) in `SELECT` that is not a part of `GROUP BY` it's a not a good thing to do. You need to apply an aggregate function to that field (`MAX`, `MIN`...). There is no way to tell deterministically which value of such a field to grab when you do `GROUP BY`

Comment: This just moves the CW and yr aliases to the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: @Awemo Can you post relevant sample data in a tabular form?

Comment: @Awemo See updated answer. If you provide sample data we can figure out your problem.