# Compute Alias values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

**Check the answer below, my QUERY is poorly written when I posted it  **

Friends,
I am using MySQL , I am trying to get the **earnings**. but gives me an error in using alias.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d') date_change,
   sum(total) AS sumTotal, sum(-2) as MOD ,  seller_id,
  SUM(sumTotal - MOD) as earnings
FROM orders where status="Complete"
group by date_change ASC;
```

Please help me to compute earnings column

Comment: You are simply not using the alias: `... GROUP BY date_change` (and not `ASC`). Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709346/using-date-format-to-group-in-mysql

Comment: I'm not saying it never happens, but DISTINCT and GROUP BY together in the same level of query is a fantastically rare thing. For further help, please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: okay thank you for the nice comments. I did modified and improve my code regarding to the date format

Comment: You cannot use output column alias in the expression for another column (in `SUM(sumTotal - MOD) as earnings`). And you cannot nest aggregate values (this is illogical). Use original expressions instead (`SUM(total - 2) as earnings`).

Comment: Much respect, thank you for explaining will fix my code, wil definitely try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Goup  by you don't need  distinct
you can't use column alias in select you must repeat the code
and you can add   an order by param (ASC) to the group by

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d') date_change,
sum(total) AS sumTotal, sum(-2) as yourMODcods ,  seller_id,
SUM(total - 2) as earnings
FROM orders where status="Complete"
group by date_change ;
```

Comment: Much respect, thank you for explaining will fix my code

Comment: I also posted the final answer for my query with an image preview. THank you so much.  Bless you!

Comment: I replaced the "mod" column as "cods" since MOD is a function in mysql

Comment: @geo_lime8  ..correct answer  updated  for avoid conflict

Answer (score 0):

[Table result , see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULebp.png)

credits to the comments and answers above this section
This is my final query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%Y-%m-%d') date_change, SUM(-2) AS 
cods, sum(total) AS sumTotal,SUM(total - 2) as earnings FROM orders 
where status="Complete" AND seller_id =20 group by date_change
```

What I learned from here is

1. The difference of Group and Select Distinct
2. Don't use mod as a column name
3. simplify the computation in a query